# Unable to consume MVC WebApi HttpPost decorated action with mutiple parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restkit-0.20

I've run into a problem while building a new MVC WebApi project where my post actions do not appear to be working correctly.

I have the following action:

```
//--
//-- POST: /api/groups/subscribe/1/groups
[HttpPost]
public GroupResponse Subscribe(int id, List<int> groups )
{
    var response = new GroupResponse();
    var manager = new UserManagement();

    try
    {
        response.Status = 1;

    var subscribedGroups = manager.GetSubscribedGroups(id).Select(g => g.GroupId).ToList();
    foreach (var subscribedGroup in subscribedGroups.Where(groups.Contains))
    {
        groups.Remove(subscribedGroup);
    }

    //-- group is a reserved word @ escapes this and treats it as a regular variable
    foreach (var @group in groups.Where(g => !manager.JoinGroup(id, g)))
    {
        response.Status = 2;
        response.ErrorMessage = Constants.SUBSCRIBE_FAIL;
    }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        response.Status = 2;
        response.ErrorMessage = Constants.SUBSCRIBE_FAIL;
        return response;
    }

    return response;
}
```

When I attempt to consume this action from rest kit I get the following error message:

```
{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50393/api/groups/subscribe'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Groups' that matches the request."
}
```

I've tried executing the action via fiddler however it looks like the api is ignoring my data being sent to the api which is confusing me at the moment.

When I attempt to use the api as follows: /api/groups/subscribe?id=1 then the api action is executed, however I'm unable to pass the the required list.

I've also setup a route to try and handle this, but it doesn't appear to be helping out at all:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "subscribe",
    "api/groups/subscribe/{id}/{groups}",
    new { controller = "Groups", action = "Subscribe", id = RouteParameter.Optional, groups = RouteParameter.Optional 
});
```

Additional info: 
When testing with fiddler I am composing my own requests as follows:

Request Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:50393
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Request Body:
{"id":1,"groups":[1,2,3,4,5]}

Comment: Is "subscribe" the only Web API route that you added? If you registered another route before the "subscribe" route, the first route might be the one that matches the request. (Web API does route matching first, then action selection.)

Comment: Nope, there's just the subscribe action. I had the same thought as well and repositioned the action as well and still had the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, tested now with fiddler.

The controller:

```
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public void Subscribe(SubscribeClass data)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
        int id = data.id;
        List<int> groups = data.groups;
        //data contains values
    }

    public class SubscribeClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<int> groups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The WebApiConfig:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AuthenticateUser",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { },
            constraints: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Subscribe" }
        );
    }
```

The JSON object send via Fiddler:

```
{ "id": 1 , "groups": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  }
```

In the Headers section in Fiddler make sure to add this header for your scenario:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and then the POST URL

```
http://localhost/api/Authentication/Subscribe
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not certain as to why but all I can get out of the application at this point is the following message:


    {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50393/api/groupapi/Subscribe'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'GroupApi' that matches the request."}

What I don't understand is that the Get action on this controller works fine but any new actions can't be found

Comment: Ahh, are you adding Content-Type, I updated the answer to indicate that as well.